# Return emoji name instead of emoji

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have this: `'1⃣'` (without the single quotes) in Python 3, which is `:one:`. Is there a way I could get the emoji (like the one above) and print the corresponding emoji (in this case :one:) name instead?

I'm getting the emoji from a discord.py reaction object.

Comment: use emoji module in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, that emoji is a two-character string. You can get the number by getting the first character of the string:

```
char = '1⃣'
print(char[0]) # 1
```

With another emoji that isn't just two characters, you can use the `unicodedata` module:

```
import unicodedata

char = '❤'
name = unicodedata.name(char)
print(name) # HEAVY BLACK HEART
```

In most cases, the name of the emote is the last word of the unicode name:

```
import unicodedata

char = '1⃣'
name = unicodedata.name(char[0])
name = name.split(' ')[-1]
print(f':{name.lower()}:')
# :one:
```

Comment: I tried the second code block on the :one: unicode, but I'm getting `name() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not str`. I'm assuming I didn't properly encode it into unicode. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: It's because the emoji you're using, `1⃣`, has two characters: `1` and `⃣`. you need to use `unicodedata.name` on the first character of that string to get `ONE`, like the last example.