# How to get string from an emoji from a reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm using discord.py and I would like to know how to get the string value of an emoji that a user has reacted with. Such as if a user reacted with a GB flag I would be able to get the string `:flag_gb:` so that I can access if they reacted with a flag and if so what flag it was.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#emoji) object  has a `name` attribute.  Looking at the [`Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#reaction) object, it looks like it the `Reaction.emoji` attribute can either be a string or an `Emoji` instance.  Try something like

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    if isinstance(emoji, discord.Emoji):
        name = emoji.name
    elif isinstance(emoji, str):
        name = emoji
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown emoji of type:", type(emoji))
    print("Name of emoji:", name)
    if "flag" in name:
        print("The emoji is a flag")
```

Comment: When using this and react with a flag I get this message - `UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f1ec' in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk`

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831593/return-emoji-name-instead-of-emoji?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  Could you add some prints to see if you're getting this from an `Emoji` object or a string in `Reaction.emoji`?